# Legendre Polynomial definite integral identity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, legendre-polynomials

I'm doing a problem involving legendre polynomials and I got stuck in this integral:

> $$I_k=\int_{-1}^{1} x P_{2k+1}(x)dx $$

Update: Note that the function in the integral is even

If $k=0$, then $I_0=2/3$, but for the other values I don't know how to proceed

For integer $k>0$ I computed the integral in [Wolfram(here is for k=1)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_(-1)%5E(1)%20LegendreP%5B3,%20x%5D%20x%20dx) and I obtained:

$$\int_{-1}^{1} x P_{2k+1}(x)dx=0 $$

Is this an identity for legendre polynomials? and if so, How can I prove it?

Comment: take a look at this, it may help you: [here!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials#Parity)

Comment: The legendre polynomials are designed such that the integral vanishes for polynomials with degree less than or equal to certain number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) $P_n(x)$ are solutions of ODE of the form
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[ A(x) \frac{dP_n(x)}{dx} \right] = \lambda_n P_n(x)
\quad\text{ with }\quad 
\begin{cases}
A(x) &= 1-x^2,\\
\lambda_n &= -n(n+1)
\end{cases}$$

For any two distinct $n, m \ge 0$, notice
$$\begin{align}
& \frac{d}{dx} \left[ A(x) \left(P_n(x) \frac{dP_m(x)}{dx} - P_m(x) \frac{dP_n(x)}{dx}\right)\right]\\
= & P_n(x) \frac{d}{dx}\left[ A(x) \frac{dP_m(x)}{dx} \right]
- P_m(x) \frac{d}{dx}\left[ A(x) \frac{dP_n(x)}{dx} \right]\\
= & (\lambda_m - \lambda_n) P_m(x)P_n(x)\end{align}
$$
We have
$$\int_{-1}^1 P_m(x)P_n(x) dx = \frac{1}{\lambda_m - \lambda_n}
\left[ A(x) \left(P_n(x) \frac{dP_m(x)}{dx} - P_m(x) \frac{dP_n(x)}{dx}\right)\right]_{-1}^1
= 0$$
because $A(x) = 0$ at $x = \pm 1$.

Since $P_1(x) = x$, this means for any $n \ne 1$, we have
$$\int_{-1}^1 xP_n(x) dx = 0$$

Comment: I forgot that $P_1(x)=x$, the problem is just orthogonality of Legendre polynomials.